# google sheets get address of first and last colored cell in row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a Gantt style sheet and This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want to develop two custom functions to calculate B and C columns. These 2 functions will take "D2:I2" and A2 as inputs and then calculate B2 and C2. But I don't know how develop those function.

[here is a link to my spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1quBkQ6kCdjogl857mAiXHr4xcVIXg4wjOTr8mSY7RW8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not sure about a custom function but with a script it can be done quite easy. It can runs every time when any cell is changed and recalculate values in B and C columns. To speed up it can recalculate only current changed row.

Comment: @YuriKhristich can you post a sample?

Comment: I was surprised that nobody posted a ready solution already. Well, it took another couple minutes and @GoranK done it! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below and add the following to you sheet's cell B2 `=get_cells(CELL("address",D2)&":"&CELL("address",I4),COLUMN(A3))`

You will need to run the function from your code editor once, to accept the required permissions.

```
// @OnlyCurrentDoc
function get_cells(dataRangeA1, colorsCol ) {
  const dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(dataRangeA1)
  const colors = dataRange.getSheet().getRange(dataRange.getRow(), colorsCol,dataRange.getNumRows(),1).getBackgrounds().map(bg=>bg[0])
  const dataColors = dataRange.getBackgrounds()
  
  const row0 = dataRange.getRow()
  const col0 = dataRange.getColumn()
  const result = dataColors.map((colorsRow, irow)=>{
    const colorToSearch = colors[irow]
    let iFirst = undefined
    let iLast = undefined
    for(let i=0; i<colorsRow.length; i+=1){
      if(colorsRow[i]===colorToSearch){
        if(iFirst==undefined){
          iFirst = i
        }
        iLast = i
      }
    }
    return [columnToLetter(col0+iFirst)+(row0+irow), columnToLetter(col0+iLast)+(row0+irow)]
  })
  return result
}


 function columnToLetter(col){
    if (col < 1 || col > 18278) {
      throw new Error('column must be in [0, 18278]')
    }
    let temp
    let letter = ''
    let column = col
    while (column > 0) {
      temp = (column - 1) % 26
      letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter
      column = (column - temp - 1) / 26
    }
    return letter
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why you have used COLUMN(A3) and not COLUMN(A2)?

Comment: you can use both, you'll get the same result. Maybe the best would be to use COLUMN(A:A)